# Trying to export backup via admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient on a Next.js API route. Error: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-admin

I'm trying to run this code to implement a Firestore backup.

But for the first time, I'm deploying it into a Next.js project.

I'll hit it on my `/api/backup` endpoint.

```
const backupHandler: NextApiHandler = async (req,res) => {
  try {
  
    const admin = initializeFirebaseAdmin();
    const PROJECT_ID = getProjectId();
    
    const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
    const DB_NAME = client.databasePath(PROJECT_ID, '(default)');

    const TODAY = getToday();  // YYYY-MM-DD
    const hashId = generateId().slice(0,5);
    const BUCKET = `gs://${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`;
    const FOLDER = `firestore-backup/${TODAY}-${hashId}`;
    const FULL_PATH = `${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}`;

    await client.exportDocuments({
      name: DB_NAME,
      outputUriPrefix: FULL_PATH,
      collectionIds: [] // CAN LIST SPECIFIC COLLECTIONS
    });

    console.log(`Backup successfully exported`);
    return res.status(200).send("Ok");
    
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
  
};
```

This is the `initializeFirebaseAdmin()` function

```
type FirebaseAdmin = typeof import("firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace")

const getServiceAccount = () : admin.ServiceAccount => {
  if (process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production"
  ||  process.env.VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF === "staging")  {
    return SERVICE_ACCOUNT.PROD;
  }
  else return SERVICE_ACCOUNT.TEST;
};

export const initializeFirebaseAdmin = (): FirebaseAdmin => {
  const account = getServiceAccount();  // THIS GETS THE SERVICE ACOUNT (VIA THE DOWNLOADED .json FILE)
  const PROJECT_ID = getProjectId();
  if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(account),
      databaseURL: `https://${PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com`  // I TRIED WITH AND WITHOUT THIS LINE: SAME RESULT
    });
  }
  return admin;
};
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> **Error: Could not load the default credentials.** Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
> at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/var/task/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:173:19)

[image]

At first I was just using the `credential` property. Then I added the `databaseURL` to see if it would solve the issue, but still, same result.

I think I'm initializing the `firebase-admin` properly. Not sure what is going wrong here.

---

**UPDATE:** Just found out that this very same code works fine on my local environment (in development), but does not work on my Next.js Node.js environment when I deploy it. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After days in hell, just found out what I was doing wrong.

I'm using `new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();` because `firebase-admin` itself won't expose any methods for us to access the `exportDocuments()` functionality.

But the fact is, when you instantiate the `FirestoreAdminClient` like that, it will not have access to the credentials that you've used on `admin.initializeApp({credentials})`.

So you need to pass the credentials to the client, by doing:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";  // OR IMPORT IT FROM SOME SINGLETON initializeFirebaseAdmin FUNCTION
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";
import SERVICE_ACCOUNT from "some-path/serviceAccount.json";

interface CredentialBody { // COPIED THIS FROM google-auth-library > auth > credentials
  client_email?: string;
  private_key?: string;
}

const backupHandler: NextApiHandler = async (req,res) => {

  const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient({
    credentials: SERVICE_ACCOUNT as CredentialBody    // <<<<<< THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
  });

  const PROJECT_ID = getProjectId();
  const DB_NAME = client.databasePath(PROJECT_ID, "(default)");

  const TODAY = getToday();  // YYYY-MM-DD
  const hashId = generateId().slice(0,5);
  const BUCKET = `gs://${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`;
  const FOLDER = `backup/${TODAY}-${hashId}`;
  const FULL_PATH = `${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}`;

  await client.exportDocuments({
    name: DB_NAME,
    outputUriPrefix: FULL_PATH,
    collectionIds: [] // CAN LIST SPECIFIC COLLECTIONS
  });

  console.log(`Backup successfully exported`);
  return res.status(200).send("Ok");

};
```

Comment: We're glad that you found a solution. Please consider accepting your own answer so other community members can use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was calling `const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();` outside the firebase cloud functions scope.

Before (not working):

```
import * as firestore from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient(); // <--- removed this

export const scheduledFirestoreExport = functions
  .region('europe-west3')
  .pubsub
  .schedule('every 24 hours')
  .onRun((context) => {

    const projectId2 = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
    functions.logger.info('Running backup for projectId2 --> ', projectId2);
    // Replace BUCKET_NAME
```

and I moved    `const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();` in the cloud function - see below

**AFTER - CODE IS WORKING FINALLY ** and the functions could be deployed

```
import * as firestore from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const scheduledFirestoreExport = functions
  .region('europe-west3')
  .pubsub
  .schedule('every 24 hours')
  .onRun((context) => {

    const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient(); // <-- put it here :)

    const projectId2 = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
    functions.logger.info('Running backup for projectId2 --> ', projectId2);
    // Replace BUCKET_NAME
    const bucket = `gs://${projectId2}-backup`;
    functions.logger.log('using the following bucket --> ', bucket);
    if (!projectId2) {
      functions.logger.warn('ProjectID not found --> escaping backup... --> ', projectId2);
      functions.logger.error('ProjectID not found --> escaping backup... --> ', projectId2);
      return;
    }
```

I hope this could help someone

cheers