# Authenticating as a service account outside of the Google Cloud environment using firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, credentials, firebase-admin, service-accounts

I'm having trouble on authenticating as a service account in my Next.js app hosted on Vercel. My code is working fine in my dev environment, but it fails with the following error message when I try to run it on Vercel Node.js v14 environment. I guess that it runs on my local machine because I'm logged in `gcloud` with my email (project owner).

This is the error I'm getting:

> **Error: Could not load the default credentials.** Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
>
> at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/var/task/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:173:19)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>
> at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/var/task/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:551:17)
>
> at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/var/task/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:109:24)
>
> at async GrpcClient.createStub (/var/task/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:252:23)

I've created the following service account to use it with my Next.js APIs.

[image]

It has all the necessary roles. I've created a JSON key and download it.

I'm using `firebase-admin` and this is how I'm initializing it:

```
export const initializeFirebaseAdmin = (): FirebaseAdmin => {
  const account = getServiceAccount();   // THIS IS THE SERVICE ACCOUNT JSON KEY (ALREADY PARSED AS AN OBJECT)
  if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(account),
    });
  }
  return admin;
};
```

This is what I think it's happening:

From: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically

[image]

- From the image above:
- I'm not setting any `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable
- So I should be on number 2. It will *"try to use the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code."*
- It's obviously failing and I getting the error

But which resource is it referring to? Which code?

The resource that is running my code is Firebase Admin? Am I not initializing it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work to authenticate the `firebase-admin` package:

```
export const initializeFirebaseAdmin = (): FirebaseAdmin => {
  const account = getServiceAccount();   // THIS IS THE SERVICE ACCOUNT JSON KEY (ALREADY PARSED AS AN OBJECT)
  if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(account),
    });
  }
  return admin;
};
```

My problem was related to the fact that I was using a client exposed from the `firebase-admin` package, that doesn't have access to the authentication from the main package. So I needed to pass the credentials to it as well. Like:

```
const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient({
    credentials: SERVICE_ACCOUNT as CredentialBody    // <<<<<< THIS IS THE SERVICE ACCOUNT JSON KEY
});
```

Refer also to: [Trying to export backup via admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient on a Next.js API route. Error: Could not load the default credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67741553/trying-to-export-backup-via-admin-firestore-v1-firestoreadminclient-on-a-next-js)